# MacOSX how to autorun a script after su - root?

Tags: macos, root, bash

Lets assume i am normal user, the i will switch to root:

```
user ~ $ su - root
Password: 
root ~ #
```

So once i logged in as `root`, i want **to run following command** automatically:

```
source .bash_profile
```

How can i have that `above command` run automatically please?

Answer (score 1):

According to the bash man page, `.bash_profile` is executed for login shells, while `.bashrc` is executed for interactive non-login shells.

In your case, you don't need to source `.bash_profile` like this.

You just need to put `source .bash_profile` in your root's `.bashrc` file

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
   source ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

Read [me](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) for better understanding of `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`

**Update**

Example:

```
[root@sgeorge-ld ~]# cat .bashrc | tail -1
echo "Testing .bashrc for a stack query"
[root@sgeorge-ld ~]# exit
logout
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld ~]$ su - root
Password: 
Testing .bashrc for a stack query
[root@sgeorge-ld ~]#
```

Comment: Its not affected. Do i need to restart something?

Comment: no. you don't need to restart anything.. are you sure you have `~/.bash_profile` ?

Comment: hmm.. so you put this `if` condition in `/root/.bashrc`. right?

Comment: yes sure. Then, i `su -` from normal user. Then when i become `root`, nothing happened.

Comment: "An exception to the terminal window guidelines is Mac OS X’s Terminal.app, which runs a login shell by default for each new terminal window, calling .bash_profile instead of .bashrc. Other GUI terminal emulators may do the same, but most tend not to.". So can you try with `.bash_profile` instead of `.bashrc`

Comment: sorry? which one to replace?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you switch to root user, you will be still your regular user's home directory. Which .bash_profile you want to execute? /Users/myuser/.bash_profile or root's /var/root/.bash_profile?

Regardless of what you would like to execute, you can edit /var/root/.bashrc (if you don't have it, create one) and add your command there.

Comment: Hi now i added `echo 'hello'` into both of: `/var/root/.bash_profile` and `/var/root/.bashrc` as the root. But when i `su - root` and reached inside again, NOTHING still happened!

Comment: Instead of `su - root`, use `sudo -s`

Comment: By the way, which shell are you using? Default shell for root is `/bin/sh`. I use `/bin/bash`. In order to do that, you can edit `/etc/passwd` file. Or if you want to keep using /bin/sh, instead of `/var/root/.bash_profile` you need `/var/root/.profile`

Comment: No, OS X Terminal is a terminal emulator. Shell is the command interpreter. If you type `echo $SHELL`, you will see what is your shell.

Comment: Also do this: Edit `/var/root/.profile`, add `echo "hello"`, and then instead of using `su - root`, use `sudo -s`. It will work.