# OSX terminal colors

Tags: macos, colors, terminal

I am using the terminal on my Macbook. I changed the bash profile so that the terminal can show colors. I used the code:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
```

in the `.bash_profile`.

But when I log in as the root, my terminal still has no colors showed up. So I was wondering how to show the color in the terminal when I log in as the root?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean that you changed your own user's bash profile successfully but it doesn't work when you log in as root? If so, you need to change the bash profile in the root user's login directory which is `/var/root`. You would find that by doing `sudo grep "^root:" /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 0):

"`.bash_profile`" is meant for the login shell.

"`.bashrc`" is the file meant for interactive non-login shells.

If you want your "`CLICOLOR`" environment variable to be picked up, maybe you should modify "`.bashrc`" to have that export, or [you should modify your "`.bashrc`" to match the answer to this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680333/macosx-how-to-autorun-a-script-after-su-root).